# SWIFT - Keep delegate values after segue and return

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, delegates

Let's say I have got 3 View Controllers: A, B and C. And I've 3 segues: A->B, B->C, C->B.
I am using delegate to pass few values from A to B, so that I can populate the label text in B VC, all good. Then I go from B to C, that is fine. But when I return from C back to B, I have errors saying the delegate value is nil. 
How can I keep the values I've got from VC A in VC B after going to C and coming back to B?
Sorry if it's confusing or if it's too simple, I am a beginner still. And thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**

**HomeViewController (A)**

```
protocol recipeDetailVariables 
{

    var recipes:[String] { get set }
    var recipeDescription: [String] { get set }
    var indexPathRow: Int {get set}

}

protocol recipeDetailVCDelegate {

    var delegate: recipeDetailVariables! { get set }

}
class HomeViewController ...
[...]

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if (segue.identifier == "segueRecipeDetail") {

            let destination = segue.destination as! RecipeDetailVC

            destination.delegate = self


        }
```

**RecipeDetailVC (B)**

```
   class RecipeDetailVC[...]

        override func viewDidLoad() {


                super.viewDidLoad()

        self.recipeTitle.text = delegate?.recipes[delegate.indexPathRow]

        self.recipeInstructions.text = delegate?.recipeDescription[delegate.indexPathRow]
}
```

Ps.: all good so far

**RecipeReviewVC (C)**

There is a segue via storyboard that brings to this VC via bar button and another segue to return to RecipeDetailVC. When I return to RecipeDetailVC it fails at the row `self.recipeTitle.text = delegate?.recipes[delegate.indexPathRow]`, saying it's nil

Comment: How are you going to B from C?  Are you pushing a new B or unwinding back to the original B?  please show some code

Comment: can you show some code snippets?

Comment: Hi @Paulw11, does this code help you guys to understand what I meant?

Comment: @Ahmad, this helps?

Comment: So, you "return" to the RecipeDetailVC via a segue?  This is your issue. You have a new instance of the detail VC. You need to use an unwind segue to go back to the existing instance

Comment: After hours trying to figure... Thanks a million for pointing me in the right direction, unwinding worked!